# How to install assembly to GAC using Msbuild?

Tags: msbuild

Is it possible to do this natively without addons or 3rd party tools?

I know there is the gacutil, but there is not an exe to run, otherwise i could've called it from the Exec task.

Has anyone done something similiar?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "there is not an exe to run". gacutil is certainly an exe you can run...

Comment: i think you're right!  i was misled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gacuti.exe can be in more than one place. It's not on the system %path% variable, so you'll have to use the full path (it will not run otherwise).
I use `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\`:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\gacutil.exe" -i MyAssembly.dll

It was reported to be found on other locations as well:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\gacutil.exe
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\gacutil.exe
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\gacutil.exe

An easy way to find it is using the windows search, or the command line: `dir gacutil.exe /s /a`.

Unfortunately, I have seed some servers where gacutil wasn't found, and I had to install the dlls manually.

Comment: Officially, gacutil is an SDK tool, so the most "correct" location would be the path found in the registry key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows" under the value "CurrentInstallFolder".

Answer (score 8):

You should use the "GacUtil" task, from MSBuild Community Tasks (free).
I think this is cleaner than calling the executable.

Comment: +1 Internally it calls GAC APIs rather than looking for the tool too BTW

Answer (score 1):

Gacutil.exe is the standard supported tool for doing "dev box" installations of .NET assemblies.  I would recommend simply using the Exec task as you mentioned to invoke it if you want to GAC your assemblies as part of a build task.

If you *really* want to do this without creating a new process, then you'd have to write a custom MSbuild task to implement the COM interop calls required to do what gacutil.exe does.  [Junfeng Zhang's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/articles/229649.aspx) would be a good starting point if you want to go this route.